# Token header in get request not working . Error 403 response is generated

Tags: ios, swift

I am sending token header using swift using GET method but response is error. I used  set value method but not working.

```
link ="some Link "
     guard let ur = URL(string: li) else {
                return
            }

        var req = URLRequest(url: ur)

        req.httpMethod = "GET"

        req.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")

        let jwt = "sometoken"

        req.setValue(jwt, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

{
error = Forbidden;
message = "Access Denied";
path = "some path";
status = 403;
timestamp = 1564133032336;
}
```

Comment: Did you try with postman ?

Comment: @ Azat I tried in postman chrome extension everything works great. but in swift not working

Comment: Do I have to make any changes in info.plist

Comment: can you show the printed request?

Comment: @aaisataev what printed request. Can you please explain further

Comment: You should not just use the token itself as a value for the `Authorization` header but also the scheme. Something like `Authorization: Bearer <token>`.

Comment: @AndréSlotta The backend api coder suggest only to use plain token which programmed in java token buider using hs256. I tried with bearer too which in case not working

Comment: Well... in that case you have to provide some more information. Can you post the working request from Postman? Is it possible that you have to send the token as a GET parameter in that case?